# Iterating through an ansible hosts group to modify a templated file at playbook runtime

Tags: ansible, mongodb

Let's say I have the following hosts groups in my Ansible inventory

```
[qrouters]
devops-qr1
devops-qr2

[shards]
devops-shrd1
devops-shrd2
devops-shrd3
```

I have to add shards to a mongodb cluster with a command similar as `sh.addShard("<$REPLICASETNAME>/comma-separated-list-of-hosts")`
(ex: `sh.addShard( "<replSetName>/s1-mongo1.example.net:27018,s1-mongo2.example.net:27018,s1-mongo3.example.net:27018")`

I'd want to write that command in a templated file in my role (let's say `roles/mongo_sharding/templates/addShards.j2`), but do not know how to iterate through the inventory file.

Please keep in mind that the number of hosts in the `[shards]` group could change from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template

```
$ cat addShards.j2
sh.addShard( "<{{ my_replica_set }}>/{{ my_hosts }}")
```

and the playbook

```
$ cat my_playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    my_replica_set: "replSetName"
    my_group: "shards"

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        my_hosts: "{{ groups[my_group]|join( ':27018,') ~ ':27018' }}"
    - template:
        src: addShards.j2
        dest: my_command
```

give

```
$ cat my_command 
sh.addShard( "<replSetName>/devops-shrd1:27018,devops-shrd2:27018,devops-shrd3:27018")
```

Comment: That simple... shows that I still need to beef up on Jinja filters !